# How to add center button to UITabBar and hide it when tab bar is hidden in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, tabbar

I am working on a custom tab bar. I added button in middle of the tab bar by using the following code:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uploader_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uploader_enabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(OpenActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
CGFloat heightDifference = button.frame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0)
{
    button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    NSLog(@"heightDifference");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not heightDifference");

    CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
    button.center = center;
}

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Now when I hide the tab bar, this button is not getting hidden.
It is visible in all view controllers.

I would appreciate your help in solving this issue.

Comment: I too facing this issue..I search around but not getting any solution...Any help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the button on `self.view`. You should ad it on `tabbar`.

```
[self.tabBar addSubview:button];
```

Comment: yeah, If  I use this ` [self.tabBar addSubview:button] `then button not showing... I am using` [self.view addSubview:button]` to show the centre button..My issue is when i am using `hide push tabbar` how I can hide this centre button.. Can you pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this.Add button to tabbar control to like below .After you can hide the Uitabbar
[myTabBarController.view addSubview:myButton];